# NxNxN Matrix Creation

Tags: c#, matrix, 3d

I wrote a small 3D matrix creation class for my project. It goes like this.

```
class _3DMatrix
    {
        public static int[, ,] m = new int[3, 3, 3];

        public _3DMatrix(int a)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < 3; x++)
            {
                for (int y = 0; y < 3; y++)
                {
                    for (int z = 0; z < 3; z++)
                    {
                        m[x, y, z] = a;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Now it seems that I have to create a NxNxN matrix that would take the N values as constructor parameters. What would be the easiest way to do it? Any tips/code snippets would help immensely.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace your constant 3 by a variable:

Please note that I changed the array to be non-static because having a static array does not make sense here.

```
class _3DMatrix
{
    public int[, ,] m;

    public _3DMatrix(int size, int a)
    {
        m = new int[size, size, size];

        for (int x = 0; x < size; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < size; y++)
            {
                for (int z = 0; z < size; z++)
                {
                    m[x, y, z] = a;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: great. How would I implement a proper Print function for that? using size for the loop? As size is a local variable.
`public void Print()
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < size; x++)
            {
                for (int y = 0; y < 3; y++)
                {
                    for (int z = 0; z < 3; z++)
                    {
                        Console.Write("{0} ", m[x, y, z]);
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine();
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }`
any ideas?

Comment: In .NET, arrays know about their own dimensions. You can call `Rank` and `GetLength` to get the size from your array.

Comment: `for (int x = 0; x < m.Rank; x++)
            {
                for (int y = 0; y < m.Rank; y++)
                {
                    for (int z = 0; z < m.Rank; z++)` using this would do? Please guide.

Comment: Can you ask a new question please? Comments aren't well suited to this.

Answer (score 0):

You can define the size of your matrix m in the constructor. As long as you do not change dimensionality, this will be fine:

EDIT: Note that I have used three separate sizes for your matrix (n1, n2, n3) but there's no reason you couldn't simply use 1 size parameter (n) if you never wanted matrices of different sizes.

```
class _3DMatrix
{
    public static int[, ,] m;

    public _3DMatrix(int a, int n1, int n2, int n3)
    {
        m = new int[n1,n2,n3];
        for (int x = 0; x < n1; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < n2; y++)
            {
                for (int z = 0; z < n3; z++)
                {
                    m[x, y, z] = a;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code (as well as all the answers ) create a NxN matrix that all the elements have the same value `a`. If this is your objective, you are fine. If not you have to pass in the creation function the matrix elements:

```
class _3DMatrix
{
    public int[, ,] m;

    public _3DMatrix(int size, int[,,] a)
    {
        m = new int[size, size, size];

        for (int x = 0; x < size; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < size; y++)
            {
                for (int z = 0; z < size; z++)
                {
                    m[x, y, z] = a[x,y,z];
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Shorter way to do it:

```
class _3DMatrix
{
    public int[, ,] m;

    public _3DMatrix(int N, int a)
    {
        m = new int[N, N, N];
        Buffer.BlockCopy(Enumerable.Repeat(a, m.Length).ToArray(), 0, m, 0, m.Length * Marshal.SizeOf(a));
    }
}
```